# C# помощь в try catch

Tags: c#

```
string  Value;
while(true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Введите 'd' для использования double или введите 'i', для использования int");

    Value = Console.ReadLine();
    if(Value == "i" || Value == "d") {
        break;
    }
}
if(Value == "i") {
 
    try
    {
        Console.Write("Введите кол-во дней: ");
        int inputDays = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] result = new int[3];
        result[0] = inputDays / 365;
        result[1] = inputDays % 365 / 30;
        result[2] = inputDays % 365 % 30;
        Console.WriteLine($"Years: {result[0]}; Months: {result[1]}; Days: {result[2]};");
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Формат данных введен не верно ");
    }
```

как после выполнения проверки если выходит catch сделать так чтобы программа запрашивала занова ввести данные и выполнился блок try

Comment: Используйте bool success = int.TryParse(value, out number); вместо влока try catch и проверяйте значение success

Comment: не совсем понятно как это реализовать в коде можете показать

Answer (score 2):

Используйте такой код вместо try ... catch:

```
do {
    Console.Write("Введите кол-во дней: ");
} while( !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inputDays));
```

или, если надо выводить сообщение об ошибке:

```
int inputDays;
bool success = false;
while(!success)
{
    Console.Write("Введите кол-во дней: ");
    success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inputDays);
    if(!success)
        Console.WriteLine("Формат данных введен не верно ");
}
int[] result = new int[3];
result[0] = inputDays / 365;
result[1] = inputDays % 365 / 30;
result[2] = inputDays % 365 % 30;
Console.WriteLine($"Years: {result[0]}; Months: {result[1]}; Days: {result[2]};");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш исходный код уже содержит нужную вам конструкцию - бесконечный цикл `while(true)` и оператор прерывания цикла `break`. При успешном выполнении `try` срабатывает `break` и происходит выход из цикла. Если возникает ошибка, то управление передается в `catch`, где нет оператора `break`, и цикл повторяется. Примените то же самое к блоку `try / catch` (добавленные операторы прокомментированы):

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    string  Value;
    while(true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите 'd' для использования double или введите 'i', для использования int");
    
        Value = Console.ReadLine();
        if(Value == "i" || Value == "d") {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(Value == "i") {
        while(true) { // бесконечный цикл
            try
            {
                Console.Write("Введите кол-во дней: ");
                int inputDays = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
                int[] result = new int[3];
                result[0] = inputDays / 365;
                result[1] = inputDays % 365 / 30;
                result[2] = inputDays % 365 % 30;
                Console.WriteLine($"Years: {result[0]}; Months: {result[1]}; Days: {result[2]};");
                break; // все завершилось успешно, выходим из цикла
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Формат данных введен не верно ");
        }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```
Введите кол-во днeй: mk,ml
Формат данных введен не верно 
Введите кол-во дней: 45
Years: 0; Months: 1; Days: 15;
```

Comment: Не стоит забывать о производительности https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/c-tryparse-vs-try-catch

Comment: @Виктор не тот случай. Ощутимая пользователем задержка - от 1 миллиона итераций. Здесь нет миллиона итераций, а самая медленная, но необходимая операция - ввод данных пользователем - в миллионы раз медленнее try/catch. Конечно, при обработке больших данных разницу в производительности нужно учесть.