# Как сделать проверку на простое число С#

Tags: c#

Есть такой код но после того как введу 2 числа консоль закрывается и все, а как сделать так чтобы консоль закрывалась только тогда когда число не простое?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool prost = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите число\n");
            int n =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
            {
                if (n % i == 0)
                {
                    prost = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (prost)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Число простое");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Число не простое");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Используйте bool success=int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n); и проверяйте, что число верное ввели, т.е. success==true   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1464767/c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d0%b2-try-catch/1464771#1464771

Comment: Вынесите в отдельный метод запрос числа у пользователя и цикл, в котором проверяете число (простое или нет) и запускайте этот метод бесконечном цикле в main, пока не условие не выдаст нужный результат, после которого вы покинете бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Если вопрос решен, вы можете принять ответ, для этого нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 3):

Кусок кода по вводу челого числа вместо

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите число\n");
int n =int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Надо обрабатывать ошибку ввода не целого числа:

```
int n;
bool success = false;
while(!success)
{
    Console.Write("Введите целое число 2-xxx: ");
    success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);
    if(!success)
        Console.WriteLine("Плохое число");
    if( n < 2 ) 
        success = false;
}
```

Ну и цикл

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
{
     if (n % i == 0) {
         prost = false;
         break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Общие алгоритмические соображения

Понятное дело, что вопрос автора тривиален, и он вовсе не касается неких простых чисел, а в общем - неверного алгоритма.

Однако же тут всё гораздо глубже, и то как автор ищет простые числа - т.е. проверяя число на делители в цикле - это и есть безумство.

Для проверки числа на простоту - используют таблицы простых чисел. Например входное число которое требуется проверить "на простоту" - это uint. Чисел умещающихся в uint - это диапазон [0, 4 294 967 295], и среди этого диапазона - и есть простые числа, какие то из них - простые, а какие то - нет.

Создавать массив таких чисел - это бессмыслица, это понятное дело гигабайты памяти. И для этого (вместо этого) используется длиннющщий битвектор. Например на лонгах.

Что такое лонг? Это 64 бита, они включены/выключены. Это набор состояний 64-ёх объектов, например чисел. В нашем случае - это "указание" на то, а простое число или нет?

Нулевой лонг в цепочке лонгов - это первые 64 числа, и каждый бит указывает на простоту числа. Собственно можно даже представить этот нулевой лонг в цепочке лонгов:

```
 0          32
 1          33
 2 prime    34
 3 prime    35
 4          36
 5 prime    37 prime
 6          38
 7 prime    39
 8          40
 9          41 prime
10          42
11 prime    43 prime
12          44
13 prime    45
14          46
15          47 prime
16          48
17 prime    49
18          50
19 prime    51
20          52
21          53 prime
22          54
23 prime    55
24          56
25          57
26          58
27          59 prime
28          60
29 prime    61 prime
30          62
31 prime    63
```

Нулевой лонг в цепочке лонгов получается следующий:

```
00110101 00010100 01010001 00000101 00000100 01010001 00000100 00010100
```

Следующий лонг указывает на диапазон [64, 127] чисел и так далее.

И для хранения всех "указаний" на простоту числа - требуется [0, 4 294 967 295] / 64 = 67108864 лонгов, т.е. такой длины нужен битвектор. И это 512 мегабайт - это много. Этот размер можно сократить, если проверять чётность. Тогда размер сокращается на 2 - это 256 мегабайт и так далее.

Обращение к такому набору лонгов (где каждый лонг хранит 64 указания на простоту числа) - тривиальное, это массив лонгов, смещения, и тривиальная битовая операция.

На этот раз решений в коде писать не буду, это снова и опять 5 строчек, а представленные соображения - это алгоритмические соображения общего рода. Которые прямо указывают на то, что проверка числа на простоту через циклы и mod - это ужас полнейший. Должно быть за O(1), и это кодированные таблицы простых чисел. А как кодировать эти таблицы - и представлено общими алгоритмическими  соображениями. Может кому нибудь пригодится.

П.С.: Естественно нужно найти таблицу простых чисел, из неё собрать битвектор, битвектор сгрузить в файлик. И этот файлик и загружать в приложение. И этот набор лонгов из файлика - и пользовать для определения простоты числа.

П.П.С.: И естественно, если вы знаете входные данные, и если число которое требуется определить на простоту - небольшое, то нет смысла грузить полный битвектор простых чисел. Битвектор нужно разбить на рейнджи, и подгружать нужный рейндж по необходимости. Но это вопрос оптимизаций, и оптимизировать можно, но не здесь же. Здесь общие алгоритмические соображения.